# What methods are available to replicate data from one database to another on a different server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server called Server1, which has a database called DB1.

My daily business data is updated in Server1.

I want this same data to be copied to another server, which named Server2. If any changes done in Server1 it is automatically reflected in the database DB2 which is in Server2.

Server1 is a Production Server and Server2 is a Demo Server. I need the data up to date in Demo Server. How I can do this?

Comment: When you say, "I need the data up to date in Demo Server," what do you mean by up-to-date. We talk about this as "freshness." So do you need demo data up to the hour? Up to the minute? Or is the backup from 3am sufficient?

Comment: I need the data up to the hour

Answer (score 1):

You could setup SQL Server Replication, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Both servers are not in same network, is it possible in this case?

Comment: Yes. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151319(v=sql.100).aspx .Though depending on how much data you actually need to replicate you may find alternatives using SSIS or  linked servers instead of Replication.